# Getting error undefined method `blank' for [1, 1]:Array in rails 3.2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am implementing a Project. In this Loan_fines table is referencing two tables that is books and categories.

I am getting the following error:-

```
NoMethodError in LoanFinesController#create

undefined method `blank' for [1, 1]:Array

app/models/loan_fine.rb:32:in `book_or_category'
app/controllers/loan_fines_controller.rb:46:in `block in create'
app/controllers/loan_fines_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

my loan fine table is as follows:-

```
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('loans_fines_id_seq'::regclass),
  category_id integer,
  book_id integer,
  loan_duration integer,
  fine_amount numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0.0,
  fine_duration integer,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT loans_fines_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I have been given this table by my senior,I dont know the meaning of `nextval('loans_fines_id_seq'::regclass)` and why it is used

Also my loan fines controller for create is as follows:-

```
 def create
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.new(params[:loan_fine])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @loan_fine.save
        format.html { redirect_to @loan_fine, notice: 'Loan fine was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @loan_fine, status: :created, location: @loan_fine }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @loan_fine.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

my loan fines model is as follows:-

```
class LoanFine < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :book_id, :category_id, :loan_duration, :fine_amount, :fine_duration

    # ------- ASSOCIATIONS -----------

    belongs_to :book

    belongs_to :category

    # ------ VALIDATIONS ------

    validate :book_or_category

  private

    def book_or_category
        if [self.book_id, self.category_id].compact.blank.size == 0
            errors[:base] << ("Please choose either book or category.")
        end
    end

end
```

I am stuck on this an I don't Know how to implement this.Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this file

```
app/models/loan_fine.rb
```

specifically line 32 as specified in the stack trace

```
app/models/loan_fine.rb:32:in `book_or_category'
```

But based on the error, you are calling `blank` instead of `blank?`. So the solution is to change `blank` to `blank?` in line 32 of your loan_fine model.

UPDATE: based on your code, you want to see if `book_id` or `category_id` is present. you have 2 options

1. `if self.book_id.blank? && self.category_id.blank?`
2. `if [self.book_id, self.category_id].reject(&:blank?).size == 0`

Comment: I am Getting undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass error,dont know why

Comment: can you update your question then? show where you're getting the error?

Comment: after i click on the create button,it goes to a new form(http://localhost:3000/loan_fines) and giving this error

Comment: which code do You want please  let me know, I wiil include it in the question

Comment: like i said, the code where you're getting the error. the location should be in the stack trace. try to read my answer and see how the stack trace pointed to where the location of the error was in your original problem

Comment: I got what You are trying to say but here it is not showing any thing in trace

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26237/discussion-between-peevee-and-jvnill)